# crawling twitter using urllib instead of twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, urllib, web-crawler

I want to crawl data from twitter. I'm using twitter api, but restricted by the rate limit, it runs very slow. 
Alternatively, I can bypass twitter api by parsing the url directly, eg. urllib package. But that is all I know.

Could you guys provide more helps about how to crawl timeline and following data from twitter without using twitter api? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using Python for programming.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what exactly you're trying to get out of it - what information are you looking for? Crawling in and of itself is quite straightforward - request page, parse out URLs, request each URL, repeat.

Comment: MattDMo Thanks for your reply. I'm new to crawler, and don't know what are you people oftenly using for crawling, especially in python. Besides, thanks to emcnaughton for introducing BS. But I usually don't know how to set the arguments in find() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use BeautifulSoup for this process.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soupy
from urllib import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen(YOUR_TWITTER_URL).read()
soup = soupy(html)
for tweet in soup.find('ol',attrs={'class':'stream-items'}).findAll('li'):
     print tweet.find('p').text
```

Comment: Thanks. How about getting following relationship?